# How do I remove a validation handler from a form?

Tags: 7, forms

I am using the *Invite by e-mail* module, which has its own `hook_form_alter()` with a validation handler. I wish to remove its validation handler and use my own validation handler.

Answer (score 1):

Use [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to change the `$form['#validate']` to be your custom validate handler.

```
function custom_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'your_form_id') {
   $form['#validate'] = array();
   $form['#validate'][] = 'my_custom_validation'; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But I have little bit of problem.The invite module already using hook_form_alter function, I want to cancel that validation too.Is this code is enough to solve my problem??

Comment: I have getting blank page with these code????

Comment: The latest version of the module has `$form['#validate'][] = 'invite_by_email_form_invite_form_validate';` which will be overwritten if your custom module has a system weight greater than this modules or if your custom module has a name alphabetically after invite_by_email

Comment: Did you create a custom module?  Change `custom_module` to your custom modules name?  Change `your_form_id` to the form_id you desired?  Change `your_custom_validate_handler` to the function name you desired?  And finally cleared the cache?

Comment: Your code goes to a blank page..Any idea?

Comment: try this,$form['#validate'] =  array(''your_custom_validate_handler');

Comment: Changed the code above to set #validate to an empty array then push your custom handler on to the list

Answer (score 1):

Use hook_form_alter() to change the $form['#validate'] to be your custom validate handler. But if you don't want to run module's validate and submit handler then first unset that specific function from $form['#validate'] and $form['#submit'] array.

```
function custom_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'your_form_id') {
    unset($form['#submit'][array_search('module_submit_handler',$form['#submit'])]);
    unset($form['#submit'][array_search('module_validate_handler',$form['#validate'])]);
    $form['#validate'][] = 'my_custom_validation'; 
    $form['#submit'][] = 'my_custom_submit'; 
  }
```

}

One more thing to remember please set your custom module weight higher so that your form alter will run after the contrib module.

Comment: This is better than removing all the validation handlers. I would rather check the validation handler exists in the array before to remove it, just in the case another module is already removing it, or administrator users temporary disable the other module.